# Cannot autowire Spring Data Repository

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, repository, autowired

I'm creating a simple application with Spring, Hibernate and MySQL database. I've done some research, but no answer was accurate. I have a repository interface, which is an extension of BaseCrudRepository, which extends ReadOnlyRepository, which is an extension of *org.springframework.data.repository.Repository*.
Code is as below:

```
package dziecko.repositories;

import dziecko.models.AreaDate;
import dziecko.utils.BaseCrudRepository;

public interface AreaDateRepository extends BaseCrudRepository<AreaDate, Integer> {}
```

AreaDate is a simple entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AREADATES")
public class AreaDate extends AbstractBase implements DtoGenerator<AreaDateDto> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2956040373671316338L;

    @Column(name = "START_TIME")
    private Date startTime;

    @Column(name = "END_TIME")
    private Date endTime;

    @Column(name = "ALARM", nullable = true)
    private Boolean alarm;

    public AreaDate() {    
    }

    public Date getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public Date getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public Boolean getAlarm() {
        return alarm;
    }

    @Override
    public AreaDateDto createDto() {
        return new AreaDateDto(id, startTime, endTime, alarm);
    }
}
```

Here is my *web.xml* file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

*app-context.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

    <!-- Enable @Controller annotation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="dziecko.repositories" />

    <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- Scan classpath for annotations (eg: @Service, @Repository etc) -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="dziecko.rests, dziecko.services">
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController" type="annotation" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <!-- JDBC Data Source. -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/dziecko" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
         <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <array>
                <value>dziecko.models</value>
            </array>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes">true</prop>
                <prop key="jadira.usertype.databaseZone">jvm</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

The problem is that even this simple test fails, because repository which is supposed to be autowired is null:

```
package dziecko.tests;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import dziecko.repositories.AreaDateRepository;

public class SpringConfigurationTest {

    @Autowired
    private AreaDateRepository adRepo;

    @Test
    public void shouldWireComponents() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(adRepo);
    }
}
```

*java.lang.AssertionError: expected object to not be null*

All entities are created inside the database. I just can't  figure out how to configure those Spring repositories properly. Everything seems to be done similar to http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html. Anyone has an idea how autowiring can be fixed here?

Comment: You never create any Spring context in your unit test, and don't run your test with a Spring test runner. How could Spring autowire a bean inside your test? Read http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#integration-testing

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't know what I've expected, but I've spent a lot of time for searching for a reason somewhere else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your test class is Spring unaware. You need to:

1. include [spring-test](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test) jar in your (test) classpath via Maven dependency or other means
2. From your test I can see you are using TestNG so the above jar will make for you available the TestNG Spring test runner:
3. Annotate your class with (supposing you don't have test context. That would have been a better practice btw):

```java
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:app-context.xml" })
public class SpringConfigurationTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will create context for tests.

Answer (score 0):

So I had *app-context.xml* file in WEB-INF folder and I didn't attach this context to test. Working version:

```
@ContextConfiguration("/META-INF/app-context.xml")
public class SpringConfigurationTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private AreaDateRepository adRepo;

    @Test
    public void shouldWireComponents() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(adRepo);
    }

}
```